# Does Spring implement its own packages scan

Tags: java, spring, reflection, component-scan

Does Spring implements its own way to scan the class in packages or does it use a external library like 'reflection':

https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of both. They use ASM for reading the class files, but use their own [`MetadataReader`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/type/classreading/MetadataReader.java) so they can offer a more flexible inheritance model for annotations than Java offers out of the box (in plain Java, annotations are only inherited from a super class. In Spring, they are also inherited from super interfaces and [meta annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-meta-annotations)).

Comment: Thanks,just what I was looking for. Now another question, can i use the internal `MetaReader` of Spring as any other library like `reflection`?, and, there is any articule about advantages of the differents `MetaReades's` libraries?